# Dockerを使用しているがApacheでlocalhost？に繋がらない。

Tags: docker, apache, docker-compose

初心者ですので、分かりづらい点があれば申し訳ございません。
※大変恐縮ですが、他サイトでもご質問しておりますが未だ解決できず困っております。

#### 解決したいこと

・ブラウザに表示されない問題を解消したいです。
※localhostに繋げたい。

#### 発生している問題・エラー

このサイトにアクセスできません。

#### 自分で試したこと

1.docker-compose.ymlでappのportsは50080:80になっているか

2.docker/app/Dockerfileでsrcディレクトリを/var/www/htmlにコピーしているか

3.Dockerfileでsrcディレクトリを/var/www/htmlにコピーしているか

4.Dockerのappというコンテナに入り、new.phpは「/var/www/html/companies/new.php」にあるか。
※new.phpは表示させたいファイルです。

5.appコンテナ内でApacheが起動しているか確認。

6.念の為Apacheを再起動

7.appコンテナとdbコンテナが起動していることを確認

8.appコンテナのログを確認

9.ここまでで下記は判明しております。

- Apacheは問題なく起動している
- （ログから）Apacheに通信が届いていない

10.src直下にファイル（src/index.php）を作成し、簡単な処理を実行。

```php
<?php
echo 'hello';
```

10-1. コマンドでこちらは実行できることを確認済み

```
docker-compose exec app php index.php
```

10-2. Apache経由から実行できることを確認するが、ブラウザで次のURLにアクセスすると、「このサイトにアクセスできません」と表示される。
http://localhost:50080/index.php
http://127.0.0.0:50080/index.php

このような状況です。
長くなり申し訳ございませんが、大変困っております。
どうか助言頂けますと幸いです。
何か必要な情報があればお伝え致します。

**実行環境**

使用OS：Windows10
Docker 20.10.2
Docker Compose 1.27.4
最後の「ローカルPCのhostsの設定？」で示しているファイルのフルパス
C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/325651) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: セキュリティソフト等が不正なポートへのアクセス等を遮断している可能性もあります。セキュリティソフトや設定をしていませんか？

Comment: ＠keitaro_soさん
ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。

セキュリティソフトや、ファイアウォールは一旦遮断も試しましたがだめでした・・・

Comment: ＠cubick♦さん
ご回答いただきましてありがとうございます。
ご指摘ありがとうございます。

明示しておきます。